# Geb: Set text in a input field

Tags: exception, text, input, geb

I created separate class for a login page like below:

```
class LoginPage extends Page{
        static at = { title == "XXX" }
        static content = {
        username(wait:true) { $(By.xpath('//input[@name="mailAddress"]'))}
        password(wait:true) { $(By.xpath('//input[@name="password"]'))}
    }       
}
```

And now accessing the username and password filed from another class called HomePageLogin with the following code:

```
Browser.drive {
    to LoginPage
    at LoginPage    
    report "AtLoginPage"    
    username.value("username")
    password.value("password")  
}
```

But getting the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: username for     class: MyPackage.HomePageLogin
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: username for class:     MyPackage.HomePageLogin
at MyPackage.HomePageLogin$_run_closure1.doCall(HomePageLogin.groovy:18)
at MyPackage.HomePageLogin$_run_closure1.doCall(HomePageLogin.groovy)
at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:1061)
at geb.Browser$drive$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:1031)
at geb.Browser$drive.call(Unknown Source)
at MyPackage.HomePageLogin.run(HomePageLogin.groovy:12)
```

How can I set the username and password?

I can set the name and password in HomePageLogin class with following code:

```
Browser.drive {
    to LoginPage
    at LoginPage    
    report "AtLoginPage"    
    $("input",name:"mailAddress").value("ID")
    $("input",name:"password").value("pass")    
}
```

But I do not want inline scripting. I want the elements to be defined and accessed through via the corresponding class which is LoginPage in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `$("input",name:"")` selectors work, try putting those in the page object, like this:

```
class LoginPage extends Page {
    static at = { title == "XXX" }
    static content = {
        username(wait:true) { $("input",name:"mailAddress") }
        password(wait:true) { $("input",name:"password") }
    }       
}
```

Comment: If I need complex element selection  by xpath, how I should use xpath than?

Comment: You can use [xpath selectors](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#using-webdriver-s-code-by-code-class-selectors), but I guess that your xpath in this case was incorrect, for some reason.

Comment: I verified my XPath with Firebug in Firefox browser and it was OK. That's why I was confused. Still searching for a workaround to use XPath instead of JQuery selector.